# difference between NTFS and FAT

Tags: windows, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [NTFS and FAT32 question](https://superuser.com/questions/225373/ntfs-and-fat32-question)  
>   [Cross-platform file system](https://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system)

What is the difference between NTFS and FAT and which is more preferable?

Comment: Huge. NTFS is preferrable, except on small-scale removable media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a read of this page might explain it for you [NTFS versus fat32](http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/fat-and-ntfs-t46351.html)

fat32 for removable media such as USB sticks and small external drives.
NTFS for main operating system disk.

or this Microsoft Link [link to ms ntfs v fat32](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/expert/russel_october01.mspx)